# Select by default value for dropdown not working by using 'track by' in angualrjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, dom-events

I am using `track by` to avoid strange values `::string` that are appending to `value` but when I select by default dropdown, dropdown is not getting selected..
this is my plunker

[Example Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AnE0zZ4Y1q45HvDuh22U?p=preview)

Comment: refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683777/angular-default-select-option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('defaultValueSelect', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
     availableOptions: [
       {id: '1', name: 'Option A'},
       {id: '2', name: 'Option B'},
       {id: '3', name: 'Option C'}
     ],
     selectedOption: '2' //This sets the default value of the select in the ui
     };
 }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-select-with-default-values-production</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="defaultValueSelect">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="mySelect">Make a choice:</label>
   
      
    <select ng-model="data.selectedOption"> 
       <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions track by option.id" value="{{option.id}}">{{ option.name}}</option> 
    </select>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <tt>option = {{data.selectedOption}}</tt><br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Working snippet of your demo

Please change your `<select>` tag as follows

```
<select ng-model="data.selectedOption"> 
   <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions track by option.id" value="{{option.id}}">{{ option.name}}</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

`<select name="mySelect"
      id="mySelect"
      ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id"
      ng-model="data.selectedOption"></select>`

`$scope.data = {
     availableOptions: [
       {id: 1, name: 'Option A'},
       {id: 2, name: 'Option B'},
       {id: 3, name: 'Option C'}
     ],
     selectedOption: {id: 2, name: 'Option B'}
    };`

http://plnkr.co/edit/yOPa3hb2nSgkpOfu8NbT?p=preview